# When to use [self] vs [weak self] in swift blocks?

Tags: swift

`[self]` is new term which we can use in blocks to avoid usage of self keyword. Then how is this different from `[weak self]`? Does `[self]` takes cares of retain cycle?

I couldn't find much info on this so any simple example with explanation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `[self]` is a strong capture vs `[weak self]` which is weak. It's just a convenience instead of prefix with `self.` in the closure

Comment: The [proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0269-implicit-self-explicit-capture.md) itself should cover the changes quite nicely.

Comment: Thank you for answers. I got bit confused as why would I use strong capture `[self]` inside block as there are chances of memory leak and `[weak self]` can save us from that?

Comment: There are cases where having a strong capturee is needed - i.e. when you want the closure to keep the object alive until it executes.

Comment: Leaks can occur when you create a retain cycle. If `self` owns the closure, and the closure strongly captures `self`, then neither the closure nor `self` can ever be released from memory. Usually, the cycle is not so direct. e.g. `self` owns a service which owns a closure which owns `self`, etc.

Comment: Well said @daltonclaybrook. I feel `[weak self]` very useful to break strong retain cycle in our class based code and I could rarely be using `[self]` for having strong hold of `self` inside capture list.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`[self]` indicates that `self` is intentionally held with a strong reference (and so some syntax is simplified). `[weak self]` indicates that `self` is held with a weak reference.

> why would I use strong capture `[self]` inside block as there are chances of memory leak

You would use this when you know there is no reference cycle, or when you wish there to be a temporary reference cycle. Capturing `self` does not by itself create a cycle. There has to be a *cycle*. You may know from your code that there isn't. For example, the thing holding the closure may be held by some other object (rather than `self`). Good composition (and decomposition of complex types into smaller types) can easily lead to this.

Alternately, you may *want* a temporary cycle. The most common case of this URLSessionTask. The docs are very valuable here (emphasis added):

> After you create a task, you start it by calling its resume() method. The session then maintains a strong reference to the task **until the request finishes or fails**; you don’t need to maintain a reference to the task unless it’s useful for your app’s internal bookkeeping.

Another common example is DispatchQueue, which similarly holds onto a closure until it finishes. At that point, it releases it, killing the cycle and allowing everything to deallocate. This is useful and powerful (and common!), when used with intent. It's a source of bugs when used accidentally. So Swift requires you to state your intentions and tries to make the situation explicit.

When you build your own types that retain completion handlers, you should strongly consider this pattern, too. After calling the completion handler, set it to `nil` (or `{_ in }` for non-optionals) to release anything that completion handler might be referencing.

One frustrating effect of the current situation is that developers slap `[weak self]` onto closures without thought. That is the opposite of what was intended. Seeing `self` was supposed to cause developers to pause and think about the reference graph. I'm not certain it ever really achieved this, but as a Swift programmer you should understand that this is the intent. It's not just random syntax.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much Rob. This is really a great explanation. I always had question about `URLSessionTask` and `DispatchQueue` about using `[weak self]` and you made it clear.

Answer (score 3):

Rob Napier has answered the memory semantics question very well (+1).

But, IMHO, that is only one part of the equation. Consider (prompted by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75561862/1271826)) the following. Should one use `[weak self]`?

```swift
Task { [weak self] in
    await self?.fetchSomeDataForThisView()
}
```

Or simply just:

```swift
Task {
    await self.fetchSomeDataForThisView()
}
```

IMHO, the concern regarding `[weak self]` capture list is often the wrong question. The broader and more important question is what do you want to do when `self` is no longer needed. The `[weak self]` effectively says “let this task continue to execute, but set `self` to `nil`”. But why continue to let the task execute if the object fetching the data is no longer needed?!

Sure, sometimes you want it to continue to execute (e.g., saving some result to persistent storage). But often, you do not (e.g., it is merely fetching data to present in the current view). In this latter case, the preferred pattern (such as employed by SwiftUI’s [`.task {…}`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) modifier) is “cancel this task when this view is no longer needed.” And if you cancel the task when the view is dismissed, then the nature of the reference to `self` becomes immaterial.

Consider:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack { … }
            .task {
                await fetchSomeDataForThisView()
            }
    }
}
```

When `ContentView` is dismissed the `.task { … }` is canceled. And, through the miracle of structured concurrency, when a task is canceled, it propagates that cancelation to subtasks (assuming that these methods supports cancelation, such as using `URLSession` methods `data(for:delegate:)` and `data(from:delegate:)`). In these cases with cancelation, that diminishes the relevance of the weak vs strong references.

Back in the day of completion handler closure code (where, sadly, correct implementation of cancelation logic was rarely considered), many would blithely let asynchronous routines continue to execute, and only consider the memory semantics of `self`. But now that we have a Swift concurrency system with first-class cancelation logic, we should ask ourselves not only when `self` should be released, but whether we want the asynchronous task to continue executing at all.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a practical approach about when to use `weak self` and when not. I divide it into two parts: analysis and effect.

#### Analysis

Look at your anonymous function ("closure" as it is often called) and think. How is it used? Is it something that will be run when it is encountered or something that is to be stored for later?

As a general simple rule, you should *never* write `weak self` unless you have an anonymous function that refers to `self` *and is stored by `self`,* causing a retain cycle that prevents `self` from going out of existence when expected.

#### Effect

Okay, but sometimes analysis leaves you confused. If in doubt about how to reason about this, just try not using `weak self` and see for yourself what the effect is.

Here's how: it's easy. Just implement `deinit` on `self`, and log (print to the console, or use Logger). Now exercise the app. Try scenarios where your closure runs and scenarios (if there are any) where it never runs. If you don't see your `deinit` log message at the time you expected `self` to be destroyed, then and only then you can start to worry that maybe `weak` is needed.