# If I use self in the closure, does it cause the memory leaks in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, memory-leaks

I'm new to Automatic reference counting and memory leaks and have (maybe) simple questions about them.
Now I get the general idea of what ARC thinks and how to avoid memory leaks, and my question is if a function has closure and requires to use self in that block, do I always need to write `[weak self]` to avoid the memory leaks?

For example...

I just made a class called ViewControllerA, and it has a function, showDeleteAlert, which delete item by the target index and target id. (sorry it's just a random class and function). In the showDeleteAlert function's delete action, there is a closure to access dataSource class's delete function. I thought I need to use `[weak self]` in the closure, since the ViewControllerA has a strong reference to showDeleteAlert function and showDeleteAlert function use self in the closure, which I think it has a strong connection to the ViewControllerA. Therefore, I put the `[weak self]` to avoid memory leaks. In that case, do I need a weak self in the closure? (if not, could you explain why I don't need a weak self please?)

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
    private var dataSource = MyDataSource()
    private var targetIndex = Int()
    private var targetId = String()

    func showDeleteAlert() {
        let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "DELETE", style: .destructive) { [weak self] _ in
            
            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                return
            }

            strongSelf.dataSource.delete(by: strongSelf.targetId, at: strongSelf.targetIndex, completion: strongSelf.reloadVC)
        }
        
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: Alert.ButtonTitle.cancel, style: .cancel)
        self.showAlert(title: alertTitle, message: nil, actions: [deleteAction, cancelAction], style: .actionSheet, completion: nil)
    }

    func reloadVC() {
        // do something for reload VCA
    }

}
```

Comment: Possibly Helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931172/should-self-be-captured-as-strong-in-a-uialertactions-handler https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27019676/is-it-necessary-to-use-unowned-self-in-closures-of-uiview-animatewithduration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64504476/when-to-use-self-vs-weak-self-in-swift-blocks

Comment: Not unless the guy named 'dataSource' holds on to an instance of the view controllder

Comment: Xcode usually tells you of one when you run the app and have a retain cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer depends on your implementation of `MyDataSource` and `showAlert(title:` method for which you haven't added any implementation details, assuming its not doing anything irrational answer mostly is **NO** you dont need `[weak self]`

Memory leak happens only when there is a cyclic reference causing the deadlock situation between two objects in the memory, stopping both of them being removed/purged from memory.

Just because you use a closure, you need not necessarily use `[weak self]` in closures capture list as long as you know there is no circular dependency or in other words cyclic reference.

**Let's analyse it:**

In your case you access `dataSource`, `targetIndex`,`targetId` and call an instance method `reloadVC` as well from closure, that means, unless you specify `[weak self]` or `[unowned self]` closure will hold a strong reference to `self`

Obviously your `self` holds a strong reference to `dataSource` and other instance properties, assuming your `dataSource` does not hold a strong reference to `self` (Cant really imagine a use case where data source holds a strong reference to self) dependency graph is not cyclic in anyway

A reference graph will be like

> Closure -> Self -> Data Source

If your Data Source itself holds a strong reference to `Self` then graph will be cyclic

> Closure -> Self -> Data Source -> Self

Or if your `Self` holds a strong reference to your `UIAlertController` or to your `UIAlertAction`

> UIAlertController -> Closure -> self -> UIAlertController
>
> UIAlertController -> UIAlertAction -> Closure -> self -> UIAlertAction

Thats why I mentioned that answer depends on your implementation of `showAlert(title:` method

Assuming you are not doing anything irrational (sorry couldnt come up with rational reasoning as to why one would hold strong reference to `UIAlertController` or `UIAlertAction`), I dont see any cyclic reference being formed hence no deadlock hence no memory leak.

**Additional info**

Assuming there is some kind of cyclic dependency and you wanna avoid memory leak, in this specific case you might wanna use `[unowned self]` instead of `[weak self]`

If you aren't sure of difference between `[weak self]` and `[unowned self]`
do read
[Shall we always use [unowned self] inside closure in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320347/shall-we-always-use-unowned-self-inside-closure-in-swift)

Hope it helps